# Retrieving the search keywords from a search result entry (Google)

Tags: url, google, search-engine, forensics

Is it possible to go back to the actual google query string given one or more URL results?

for example, if I do a search using the keyword "pippo" I get this first entry:

http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pippo.it%2F&ei=kFSeVdCSDeGC7galoYKwCA&usg=AFQjCNFFQZzm2gZe25THufXZmDrZMWkzFg&sig2=2l9_gUfNQMHfipPwFnVkRA&bvm=bv.96952980,d.ZGU

Is it possible, given that entry, to retrieve back the "pippo" keyword? Or at least a set of keywords which most likely bring such entry.

Comment: The [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is probably more appropriate for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

The search query is not there. For privacy Google redirects pages in such a way that the query is not passed on to web sites.